# How to pin target iOS SDK version when building with xcodebuild

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I build an IPA using `xcodebuild` on CI (actually, I have a Flutter app and build it for iOS with `flutter build ipa` but it calls `xcodebuild` under the hood). Every now and than, for example right now, a new iOS SDK comes out (17.2 as of right now) and it breaks the build until I install this new 'platform' in Xcode on the CI server. This would mean the build somehow knows there is a newer iOS SDK version (how does this work?), and it automatically wants to use it - but it can't find it (I haven't installed it yet) and fails. This is very disruptive as I need to let everything go and fix this ASAP.

Is it possible to 'pin' (explicitly state) the SDK version I want to use for the build, and not always try to use the latest one? I could then decide at my own pace to pace when to upgrade to the latest one.